# Static Variables in Robot Framework

Tags: python, static, robotframework

Is there any such thing as a static type of variable in robot framework? and if so how do i invoke it? or is the solution to do it via a python file?

The problem i'm trying to fix is, i want a variable to be set once and for it to remember the value that is set. Unfortunately this variable is in a resource file (it's separate to my test suite files).

Comment: Yes, i'm setting the variable to be the time at which it starts

Comment: In that case you can check out my answer.

Comment: Are you asking for something truly static, where robot will throw an error if you try to change the value after it's been set?

Comment: @BryanOakley that's not the issue i'm trying to fix but will be curious to see how you can implement such a feature

Comment: So, by "static" you're just asking how to set a variable, and don't care that it's unchangeable? I'm just trying to understand what you mean by the word "static".

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can set static variables in robot framework. Your resource file should have something like this in it.

```
*** Settings ***
...
*** Variables ***
${MyVariable}    MyValue

*** Keywords ***
...
```

Your test should look something like this

```
*** Settings ***  

Resource    (Path to resource file)

*** Test Cases ***
My Test Case
[Documentation]    This is documentation
My keyword    MyVariable
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the following suite structure:

```
/test_folder
    __init__.robot
    variables.resource
    test_s1.robot
    test_s2.robot
    test_s3.robot
```

---

Now in your `variables.resource` file you can create and initialize your variable like:

```
*** Keywords ***
Setup Static Variable
    ${my_static}=    Init My Static    # Get time here
    Set Suite Variable    ${my_static}    children=true
```

Here with the [Set Suite Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable) you can make your variable accessible in the current suite (in which this keyword is actually called) and with the `children=true` option, in all sub-suites. This means all test suite files in the folder for example.

---

Next step is to create your `__init__.robot` file:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource            variables.resource
Suite Setup         Setup Static Variable
```

The current suite will be `test_folder` and the children will be `test_s1`, `test_s2` and `test_s3`. `${my_static}` will be accessible in all of them. The `Setup Static Variable` keyword will be executed once, when the execution reaches the `test_folder`.

---

In your test suite files you can use the variable even without importing the resource file.

test_s1.robot:

```
*** Test Cases ***
My First Test
    Log    ${my_static}
```

---

If your variable is a constant and not calculated during run-time, @Justin's answer is what your are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bence, i've tried your solution out but it doesn't seem to like it. I'm getting the erro: 
"My First Test                                                                                                                                                   | FAIL |
Variable '${my_static}' not found." I am using RIDE as my editor, is the __init__.robot file correct? I've looked around and some people are saying the you shouldn't call a resource file in the __init__ file?

Comment: @WorkerBee How do you start the test? In the log file can you see the Suite Setup executed? Once you have the __init__.py  you have to start your suites from that folder. So in my example with the following command line option: `--suite test_folder.test_s1`. About the resource file in the init file, I use it like that myself, did not notice any problem with it so far. I will look around too.