# Variable from one Test cant be used in other(Variable 'token' is used, but not defined)

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I have the following two tests,

```
*** Settings ***

Library     CustomizeLibrary

*** Variables ***

${username}    anti
${password}    anti
${headers}    {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

*** Test Cases ***

GET token based on existing user

    ${token}=    Customize Get Token    http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/token    ${username}    ${password}    ${headers}
    Set suite variable    ${token}


GET Users

    ${token}    Customize Get Token    http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/token    ${token}  (Gives error: Variable 'token' is used, but not defined)
```

**${token}** is defined and set as suite variable in previous test not yet able to use it, Any sugession ?

Comment: What does "not yet able to use it" means? Do you get an error? Is it set to the wrong value? Does robot crash without completing the test? Have you logged the value in both tests to see what the value is?

Comment: When I run your code after creating my own `CustomizeLibrary` with a `customize get token` keyword, it works exactly as it should. When I add a log statement inside of `GET Users`, the token from the first test is logged. Perhaps the problem isn't in the test, but rather in your own custom keyword.

Comment: Also, the error you report doesn't look like an error that robot would throw. That is more evidence to me that it's your custom keyword that is throwing the error rather than robot.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at setting the suite variable during Suite Setup by calling a keyword to initialize the variable. It will run before tests and eliminates dependency between tests.

Here is a dummy example:

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup  Init Suite Variable

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: Test 1 - Suite Variable
    Log To Console  ${suite_variable}

Scenario: Test 2 - Test Variable 
    Init Test Variable
    Log To Console  ${test_variable}

*** Keywords ***
Init Suite Variable 
    Set Suite Variable  ${suite_variable}  I'm at suite level

Init Test Variable 
    Set Test Variable   ${test_variable}  I'm at test level
```

In your case it would look like...

```
*** Settings ***
Library     CustomizeLibrary
Suite Setup  GET token based on existing user

*** Variables ***
${username}    anti
${password}    anti
${headers}    {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

*** Test Cases ***
GET Users
    ${token}    Customize Get Token    http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/token

*** Keywords ***
GET token based on existing user
    ${token}=    Customize Get Token    http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/token    ${username}    ${password}    ${headers}
    Set suite variable    ${token}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called a "static variable", a variable that is not restricted to a single test/method/class instance (Google for more info). This variable exists outside all your tests. Robotframework calls it a 'suite variable', see also http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable

How to implement: [Static Variables in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109182/static-variables-in-robot-framework)

```
*** Settings *** 
... 
*** Variables *** 
.... other variables ....

*** Test Cases ***
GET token based on existing user
    ${token}=    Customize Get Token    http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/token    ${username}    ${password}    ${headers}
    Set suite variable    ${token}

GET Users
    ${token}    Customize Get Token    http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth/token
```

Remark: the other answer is better, it adresses the intialization part so tests can be commented out/skipped/run in different order

Comment: Robot doesn't have the concept of static variables.

Comment: I am not a robotframework expert, but what are the things under *** variables ***? Looks like they exist over tests? Other incredibly dirty solution, write it to a local file and retrieve it (yuck, but gets job done)

Comment: @TacoVerhagen They don't fit the definition of static variable but conceptually you're not wrong in your suggestion for using variables in the *** Variables *** section - if it wasn't for the fact that you can't run keywords in the variable section (the keyword will just be treated as part of the variable value)

Comment: _"what are the things under *** variables ***"_ - they are variables, but they aren't static.

Comment: so, I tried to run keyword in Variables section and it does not run keyword but assign the whole as a string to the variable, if that would have worked that could be great colution any other sugesstions ?

Comment: I edited it using a 'suite variable', but the other answer is even better. Upvote that one